# How to use the If statement in localization and globalization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am beginner to ASP.NET Core. There are two Description properties in my model, English and Spanish.
I am interested in the question: is it possible through the statement If to localize an object from the database in this way?

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IViewLocalizer localizer
...
@if (localizer.ToString() == "es")
{
    @localizer["Job.DescriptionEs"]
}
else
{
    @localizer["Job.DescriptionEn"]
}
```

Comment: `if` is not an operator. It's a statement. (Whereas `+`, `-`, `.`, `?:`, `??`, `typeof()` are operators).

Comment: What is `localizer` in this context?

Comment: Will you ever need to support additional languages? You probably wouldn't want to have separate `else if` statements for every language everywhere in your `.cshtml` files - there are better ways to localize.

Comment: Hi Dai! Thx! I use standart Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IViewLocalizer. In the project I am using a Resource file for each language. I want to try to make sure that when switching languages ​​in views from the model, the desired description is shown. Sry for my Eng =(

Comment: switching the key like this is a very bad design. You should use just one same key `Job.Description`. The switch should be somewhere internally in the code behind. Imagine that you have multiple dictionaries, each one is used for a language. At the very beginning of each request, the dictionary corresponding to the current request language should be picked/selected. So in the code after that (e.g: in the Razor view or page), that dictionary is the one behind the scene. The keys are same for all dictionaries (as well as languages).

Comment: @Hopeless Razor/cshtml does not use "code-behinds", but you're right insofar as the responsibility for returning the correct localized value for a given key lies with `localizer`, not its consumer.

Comment: @Dai you might misinterpret what I commented before. I talked about `the switch` here, and I would not use any kind of switch in the Razor/cshtml. The code behind I meant here is the code not used in Razor/cshtml (such as some code in the controller or in the `action filters`). I did not find a more appropriate word for what I meant.